# How to run js if page has certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file in my header that runs on every page. Most of my pages use this js however there are some that don't. How can I make it so I don't get this error on pages that don't have this id?

js:

```
var menuitems=document.getElementById(tabid).getElementsByTagName("a")
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

Comment: Check that it is not empty.

Comment: I think Your `tabid` is not a variable and it is id of your parent element. If yes then use `'tabid'` instead of `tabid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `jQuery` like this.

```
if($(tabid).find('a').length){
  runsJscode();
  //or
  //apend script in the head
}
```

Comment: This code does not work, it would return all anchor tags not just the anchors inside given ID, I dont know how people upvote without thinking it

Answer (score 3):

Include if condition:

```
var tabEl = document.getElementById(tabid);
if(tabEl) {
    var menuItems = tabEl.getElementsByTagName("a");
}
```

or else there is a trick:

```
var menuItems = document.getElementById(tabid) && document.getElementById(tabid).getElementsByTagName("a");
```

I don't know how consistent the latter one is though. I suggest the former one.

Comment: On the pages that it doesn't exist I now get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @user2570937 you might be not using the exact above code.

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead and check if it's `null`.

```
var menuItems = document.getElementById(tabid);
if (menuItems != null) {
  menuItems = menuItems.getElementsByTagName("a");
  //blah blah more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var menuItems = document.getElementById(tabid);
if (menuItems != null || menuItems != undefined) {
  // your code here

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById() returns null if correspoding tag element is not found
```

so make sure element exists in your DOM, To do that verify with value `null`

```
var items = document.getElementById(tabid);
if(items != null){
    items = items.getElementsByTagName("a");
   // do your stuff 
} 

// jQuery way
var items = $("#"+ tabid + " a"); // selector for descendent elements 
if(items.length){
  // do your stuff
}
```